# Vue.js deep watching of computed property using other computed property objects

Tags: vue.js

I am aware of deep watching of properties using the handler in the "watch" section, but I am not seeing how to make vue deep watch in a getter/setter computed property.

Essentially I have something like this, of which vue is not able to observe the changes.

**How do I tell vue to observe the changes of "someComputedProperty"?**

```
computed: { 
    someComputedProperty: {
      set (value) {
        this.someComputedPropertyObject[this.someOtherObject.id] = value;
      },

      get () {
        return this.someComputedPropertyObject[this.someOtherObject.id];
      }
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance,

Erion

Comment: Computeds don't work like that. This is the case for a watcher.

Comment: Estus, thanks, but in my situation a watcher would not make a difference. I am looking and reasonably thinking that Vue should detect that the objects referenced in the computed property changed and should be able to notify of the change. @DecadeMoon’s recommendation is closer to what I was thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `someComputedPropertyObject` is a Vue computed property, its value won't be made observable by design (if it creates a new object).

Furthermore, does `someComputedPropertyObject` have the `this.someOtherObject.id` property defined upfront? If not, you're creating a new property which Vue cannot observe. Use [`Vue.set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) (or `this.$set`) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I will give that Vue.set a try. The object [this.someOtherObject] is a computed property (using a getter/setter) and it's the result of a user interaction.